# JSON containing ArrayList and HashMap

Tags: java, json, ajax, arraylist, hashmap

My servlet has an `ArrayList` and a `HashMap` object that I want to be sent to my jsp via AJAX. How do I do that and then how do I separate them out after getting them as javascript responseText? (Cant use jQuery)

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
String json1= new Gson().toJson(al);
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
String json2= new Gson().toJson(hm);
```

What I havedone so far

```
ServletOutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
String json = "[" + json1 + "," + json2 + "]";
System.out.println(json);
os.write(json.toString().getBytes());
flushCloseOutputStream(os);
res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
```

And then on jsp side

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
var workDesc = jsonResponse[1];
var thirdPartyData = jsonResponse[0];
```

My question is, is this the correct way of sending response?

Comment: Is there a request?  Do you necessarily need the server to initiated the response?  The correct way to do this is by creating a web service then initiating a XHR request from the client to the server, but that assumes there is a request.  If there isn't a request then you might need to use some type of message queue or long polling

Comment: there is a request. I will edit my code to show what I have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

[GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) will do the trick. A simple example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.util.HashMap;

class App {

    private static final Type hashMapStringApp = new TypeToken<HashMap<String,App>>(){}.getType();

    private String attribute;

    public App(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson(); 

        // Complex object to JSON
        HashMap<String, App> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("1", new App("Attr1"));
        map.put("2", new App("Attr2"));
        String json = gson.toJson(map);
        System.out.println(json);

        // JSON to complex object
        HashMap<String, App> fromJson = gson.fromJson(json, hashMapStringApp);
        System.out.println(fromJson.get("2").getAttribute());
    }

    public void setAttribute(String attribute) {
        this.attribute = attribute;
    };

    public String getAttribute(){
        return this.attribute;
    }
}
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```